# rndis & centos 7: can't connect to usb modem

Tags: networking, centos7, modem

i have 4g modem, which shoudld work via `rndis`. 
after inserting it in usb, i get these network interfaces:

- enp0s29f2u1
- eth0

but, i can't configure it.

after doing `eject -t cdrom` i get another one interface: enp0s29f2u2. 
and that one i can configure.

so now i have:

```
[root@nethvo ~]# ifconfig enp0s29f2u2
enp0s29f2u2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::ae50:43ff:fe6f:d8eb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ac:50:43:6f:d8:eb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 3593027  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 3593027
        TX packets 2126  bytes 212899 (207.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[root@nethvo ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         84.204.31.121   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp2s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s29f2u2
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp0s29f2u2
84.204.31.120   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 enp2s0
84.204.31.121   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 enp1s9
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 wlp1s10
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1010   0        0 enp0s29f2u2
192.168.46.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp1s9
192.168.47.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlp1s10
192.168.140.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0
[root@nethvo ~]# ping -c 2 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.2 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1001ms
pipe 2
[root@nethvo ~]# telnet 10.0.0.1 80
Trying 10.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 10.0.0.1: No route to host
```

what is missing?

upd. from log message:

```
Jun 26 15:51:10 nethvo kernel: rndis_host 3-2:1.0 enp0s29f2u2: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:1d.2-2, RNDIS device
Jun 26 15:51:10 nethvo avahi-daemon[642]: Withdrawing workstation service for enp0s29f2u2.
Jun 26 15:51:10 nethvo kernel: usb 3-2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
Jun 26 15:51:10 nethvo kernel: rndis_host 3-2:1.0: RNDIS init failed, -71
Jun 26 15:51:10 nethvo kernel: rndis_host: probe of 3-2:1.0 failed with error -71
```

Answer (score 0):

rndis is for Windows only as it is a MSFT proprietary driver. You will not be able to configure it on Centos easily unless you get lucky and manage to find a generic chipset driver from ASIX or equivalent which is close enough to treat it as a "usbnet" device. In my experience this fails often as well but will at least let you use ethtool and ifconfig to get more details even if you can't ping or trace it with tcpdump.

Comment: strange, that on centos 6 this modem works like a charm... so i solved it by downgrading :(